# Работа с MS Word с помощью C#

Tags: c#, ms-word

Подскажите сайты, где четко расписана работа с Word через C#. Т.е. там расписаны все методы, свойства и т.п. Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать бесплатную библиотеку DocX.

Ссылки:

[Гайд на русском](https://progtask.ru/rabota-s-word-pri-pomoshi-c-sharp/)

[Репозиторий на GitHub](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/DocX)

Также можно использовать другую библиотеку от Microsoft:

Ссылки:

[Англоязычный гайд](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/muralidharan.d/how-to-create-word-document-using-C-Sharp/)

[Документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.document?view=word-pia)